# Passenger: 100% CPU

Tags: macos, passenger

I'm running Passenger and, when I restart Apache, I get a `PassengerWatchdog` process that hits 100%  of the CPU.

Any suggestions?

I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.4 with Passenger 4.0.5 and Ruby 2.0.0p195.

Using the Mac OS X Activity Monitor here's what I got when I Sampled it:

```
Analysis of sampling PassengerWatchdog (pid 3477) every 1 millisecond
Process:         PassengerWatchdog [3477]
Path:            /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/passenger-4.0.5/agents/PassengerWatchdog
Load Address:    0x1055ce000
Identifier:      PassengerWatchdog
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  httpd [3473]

Date/Time:       2013-06-24 17:59:52.311 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)
Report Version:  7

Call graph:
    2566 Thread_76210   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)
    + 2566 start  (in libdyld.dylib) + 7  [0x7fff8bfb77e8]
    +   2566 exit  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 15  [0x7fff957b7f57]
    +     2566 __cxa_finalize  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 200  [0x7fff957b6307]
    +       2566 __tcf_12  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 27  [0x1055cf2db]  Main.cpp:95
    +         2566 boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::ServerInstanceDir::Generation>::~shared_ptr()  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 37  [0x1055dab89]  shared_ptr.hpp:165
    +           2566 boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count()  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 40  [0x1056171d4]  shared_count.hpp:305
    +             2566 boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release()  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 86  [0x1055da0de]  sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:145
    +               2566 boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<Passenger::ServerInstanceDir::Generation>::dispose()  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 28  [0x1055def22]  sp_counted_impl.hpp:78
    +                 2566 void boost::checked_delete<Passenger::ServerInstanceDir::Generation>(Passenger::ServerInstanceDir::Generation*)  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 42  [0x1055fa57a]  checked_delete.hpp:34
    +                   2566 Passenger::ServerInstanceDir::Generation::~Generation()  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 57  [0x1055fa4db]  ServerInstanceDir.h:171
    +                     2566 free  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 199  [0x7fff957888f8]
    +                       2566 szone_free_definite_size  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 1908  [0x7fff9578e7cd]
    +                         2566 tiny_free_list_remove_ptr  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 330  [0x7fff95791d67]
    +                           2566 _sigtramp  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 26  [0x7fff9575d94a]
    +                             2566 Passenger::abortHandler(int, __siginfo*, void*)  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 1039  [0x105629cbf]  Base.cpp:867
    +                               2566 Passenger::forkAndRedirectToTee(char*)  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 63  [0x1056276df]  Base.cpp:791
    +                                 2566 Passenger::asyncFork()  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 13  [0x10561967d]  Utils.cpp:972
    +                                   2566 fork  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 12  [0x7fff95797411]
    +                                     2566 _cthread_fork_prepare  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 98  [0x7fff95777206]
    +                                       2566 _malloc_fork_prepare  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 61  [0x7fff95789719]
    +                                         2566 szone_force_lock  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 71  [0x7fff95793caa]
    +                                           2566 _spin_lock$VARIANT$mp  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 25,53,...  [0x7fff9575dfa9,0x7fff9575dfc5,...]
    2566 Thread_76212
      2566 thread_start  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 13  [0x7fff9575c1e1]
        2566 _pthread_start  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 327  [0x7fff9576f7a2]
          2566 thread_proxy  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 141  [0x10563405d]  thread.cpp:153
            2566 boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(boost::function<void ()>, boost::shared_ptr<oxt::thread_local_context>), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<boost::function<void ()> >, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<oxt::thread_local_context> > > > >::run()  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 37  [0x1055e6979]  thread.hpp:78
              2566 boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(boost::function<void ()>, boost::shared_ptr<oxt::thread_local_context>), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<boost::function<void ()> >, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<oxt::thread_local_context> > > >::operator()()  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 92  [0x1055e694e]  bind_template.hpp:20
                2566 void boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<boost::function<void ()> >, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<oxt::thread_local_context> > >::operator()<void (*)(boost::function<void ()>, boost::shared_ptr<oxt::thread_local_context>), boost::_bi::list0>(boost::_bi::type<void>, void (*&)(boost::function<void ()>, boost::shared_ptr<oxt::thread_local_context>), boost::_bi::list0&, int)  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 157  [0x1055e680d]  bind.hpp:313
                  2566 oxt::thread::thread_main(boost::function<void ()>, boost::shared_ptr<oxt::thread_local_context>)  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 413  [0x10563b52d]  implementation.cpp:331
                    2566 boost::function0<void>::operator()() const  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 143  [0x10562372b]  function_template.hpp:767
                      2566 boost::detail::function::void_function_invoker0<void (*)(), void>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&)  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 29  [0x1055e1cdd]  function_template.hpp:112
                        2566 ServerInstanceDirToucher::threadMain()  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 28  [0x105604e0c]  ServerInstanceDirToucher.cpp:38
                          2566 oxt::syscalls::sleep(unsigned int)  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 49  [0x105641151]  system_calls.cpp:581
                            2566 oxt::syscalls::nanosleep(timespec const*, timespec*)  (in PassengerWatchdog) + 113  [0x105640eb1]  system_calls.cpp:620
                              2566 nanosleep  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 163  [0x7fff957f9800]
                                2566 __semwait_signal  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff8d9d5386]

Total number in stack (recursive counted multiple, when >=5):

Sort by top of stack, same collapsed (when >= 5):
        __semwait_signal  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        2566
        _spin_lock$VARIANT$mp  (in libsystem_c.dylib)        2566

Binary Images:
       0x1055ce000 -        0x105678fef +PassengerWatchdog (??? - ???) <F793DD00-F0BC-37AE-BD0D-114012A1CF6D> /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/passenger-4.0.5/agents/PassengerWatchdog
    0x7fff651ce000 -     0x7fff6520293f  dyld (210.2 - ???) <36CAA36E-72BC-3E48-96D9-B96A2DF77730> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8a34e000 -     0x7fff8a3b7fff  libstdc++.6.dylib (56.0.0 - compatibility 7.0.0) <EAA2B53E-EADE-39CF-A0EF-FB9D4940672A> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x7fff8a7ef000 -     0x7fff8a7f5ff7  libunwind.dylib (35.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <21703D36-2DAB-3D8B-8442-EAAB23C060D3> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff8ac52000 -     0x7fff8ac5dfff  libsystem_notify.dylib (98.5.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <C49275CC-835A-3207-AFBA-8C01374927B6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff8adb5000 -     0x7fff8adbdfff  liblaunch.dylib (442.26.2 - compatibility 1.0.0) <2F71CAF8-6524-329E-AC56-C506658B4C0C> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff8add3000 -     0x7fff8addafff  libcopyfile.dylib (89.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <876573D0-E907-3566-A108-577EAD1B6182> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff8af9d000 -     0x7fff8afa2fff  libcache.dylib (57.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <65187C6E-3FBF-3EB8-A1AA-389445E2984D> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff8b3b1000 -     0x7fff8b3fdff7  libauto.dylib (??? - ???) <AD5A4CE7-CB53-313C-9FAE-673303CC2D35> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff8b481000 -     0x7fff8b4b7fff  libsystem_info.dylib (??? - ???) <4FFCA242-7F04-365F-87A6-D4EFB89503C1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff8bfb2000 -     0x7fff8bfb3ff7  libdnsinfo.dylib (453.19.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <14202FFB-C3CA-3FCC-94B0-14611BF8692D> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
    0x7fff8bfb5000 -     0x7fff8bfb8ff7  libdyld.dylib (210.2.3 - compatibility 1.0.0) <F59367C9-C110-382B-A695-9035A6DD387E> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff8c4cf000 -     0x7fff8c4f1ff7  libxpc.dylib (140.43.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <70BC645B-6952-3264-930C-C835010CCEF9> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff8c853000 -     0x7fff8c8a2ff7  libcorecrypto.dylib (??? - ???) <CE0C29A3-C420-339B-ADAA-52F4683233CC> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff8c8a3000 -     0x7fff8c8c8ff7  libc++abi.dylib (26.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <D86169F3-9F31-377A-9AF3-DB17142052E4> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff8d537000 -     0x7fff8d538fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib (59.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <D92DCBC3-541C-37BD-AADE-ACC75A0C59C8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff8d9c3000 -     0x7fff8d9deff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2050.24.15 - compatibility 1.0.0) <A9F97289-7985-31D6-AF89-151830684461> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff8e4c4000 -     0x7fff8e4d2ff7  libsystem_network.dylib (??? - ???) <0D99F24E-56FE-380F-B81B-4A4C630EE587> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff8edff000 -     0x7fff8ee01ff7  libunc.dylib (25.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <92805328-CD36-34FF-9436-571AB0485072> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff8ef14000 -     0x7fff8ef16fff  libquarantine.dylib (52.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <143B726E-DF47-37A8-90AA-F059CFD1A2E4> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff8fd19000 -     0x7fff8fd2eff7  libdispatch.dylib (228.23.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <D26996BF-FC57-39EB-8829-F63585561E09> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff90bcc000 -     0x7fff90bcdff7  libremovefile.dylib (23.2.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <6763BC8E-18B8-3AD9-8FFA-B43713A7264F> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff90bce000 -     0x7fff90bdcfff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (50000.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <BAAFE0C9-BB86-3CA7-88C0-E3CBA98DA06F> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff91673000 -     0x7fff916dbff7  libc++.1.dylib (65.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <20E31B90-19B9-3C2A-A9EB-474E08F9FE05> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff91890000 -     0x7fff91891fff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (??? - ???) <8548E0DC-0D2F-30B6-B045-FE8A038E76D8> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff9285c000 -     0x7fff9285dff7  libSystem.B.dylib (169.3.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <9089D72D-E714-31E1-80C8-698A8E8B05AD> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff92fdd000 -     0x7fff92fddfff  libkeymgr.dylib (25.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <CC9E3394-BE16-397F-926B-E579B60EE429> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff937a9000 -     0x7fff938c192f  libobjc.A.dylib (228.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <90D31928-F48D-3E37-874F-220A51FD9E37> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff93e3a000 -     0x7fff93e40fff  libmacho.dylib (829.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <BF332AD9-E89F-387E-92A4-6E1AB74BD4D9> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff93ed1000 -     0x7fff93ed6fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (30.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <08F8731D-5961-39F1-AD00-4590321D24A9> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff9556e000 -     0x7fff9556fff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (??? - ???) <B739DA63-B675-387A-AD84-412A651143C0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff9575b000 -     0x7fff95827ff7  libsystem_c.dylib (825.26.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <4C9EB006-FE1F-3F8F-8074-DFD94CF2CE7B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff95a41000 -     0x7fff95a49ff7  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (??? - ???) <BDCB8566-0189-34C0-9634-35ABD3EFE25B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff95abe000 -     0x7fff95aecff7  libsystem_m.dylib (??? - ???) <B434BE5C-25AB-3EBD-BAA7-5304B34E3441> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
```

Comment: I have the same issue running with ruby 1.8.7. Same version of OSX and Passenger. Killing the PassengerWatchdog process helps, the next one spawned does not peg the CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue and has been resolved. Though the fix is committed, it has not been released as a gem. Look for the next version, 4.0.6, which should contain the fix.

For now, you may either downgrade passenger (I haven't pinpointed the version which introduces this problem, my guess is to try version <= 4.0.4) or work from the source repo.

Here is the bug tracker page: 
https://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=908

We are experiencing this problem in FreeBSD (the base of OS X), and hope this will resolve it there as well.

Comment: UPDATE: The patch fixed the issue on FreeBSD as well. We were skeptical as the code included references to "Apple" or "Darwin," but it did work on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by downgrading to 4.0.3, then doing a hard stop and then a start of Apache after killing the rogue processes using killall.